# Select woocommerce chosen shipping method price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to select the chosen_shipping_method price in woocommerce using this code:

```
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
foreach ($packages as $i => $package) {
    $chosen_method = isset(WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[$i]) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[$i] : '';
}
echo $chosen_method;
```

the code works, but it prints the ID, and i cannot figure out how to make it print out the price.

Here's package structure:

[image]

What i get with my code is `table_rate_shipping_shipping_self_install`, but what i need is the cost for the selected element, and not the id.

i tried to change the code like this:

```
foreach ($packages as $i => $package['rates']) {
    $chosen_method = isset(WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[$i]) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[$i] : '';
}
```

But it printed out the id, same as before.

Any ideas? sorry i'm a bit new to php.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get the ID or the WC_Shipping_Rate class?

Comment: I think the id as i print it as a string and it works

Comment: What do you get if you don't add the [$i] in your code

Comment: Without the [i] $chosen_method is an array and it is like this -> [0='table_rate_shipping_shipping_self_install']

Comment: May I ask what you used to print the `$package` array in your screenshot like that?

Comment: Yes, It's phpstom (software that I use) php debugging feature. You can inspect it like the screenshot above while debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try this inside your foreach loop?

```
$rate = $package['rates'][$chosen_method]->cost;
```

Comment: Just tried. $rate returns null and i have this warning ->  Warning: Illegal offset type in \functions.php on line 649

Comment: Sorry! i had i typo. Yes it worked now. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If yo need to get price of shipping method that was chosen by user and stored in session, you should try this:

```
$chosen_shipping_method_price = WC()->session->get('cart_totals')['shipping_total'];
```